# EC2 Instance Disk Partition

Tags: partitioning, amazon-ec2

I have an xlarge EC2 instance which is having Oracle installed on it and it is of 50GB of size. Oracle is using only 20 GB space. Now, I have to do partition of this 50GB disk so that I have 35 GB Oracle space and 3 other partitions with 5GB space equally.

Not sure if this is something recommended to do or shall I create 3 separate volumns of 5GB in size and mount them on this? Also, what is data loss factor in both the cases.

Please let me know the thoughts as this is something I will be doing for the first time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're lots of variables at play here, and you provided way too little information.

First of all, I would check if you can repartition your drive at all. Chances are there no GTP/MBR on the disk. In this case, you are out of options and should go with mounting additional EBS volumes.

Second, you might or might not have volume groups. Check with `vgs`/`vgdisplay`.

Third, you might or might not have software RAID array. Check with `cat /proc/mdstat` or `mdadm --detail`.

After exploring your current setup you'll have a better idea about what to do next. **Safe approach:** just create new EBS volumes and attach them to your instance.

Comment: That's why we normally don't answer questions like these...  Too many possibilities...  Hint: to remove the negative reputation points you currently have, delete your answer and these will be reversed (I do this too for answers of mine that give me negative rep)  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks for answering all the possibilities and as I checked I found that I cannot do partition in this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sergey - Guys like you who help people like us are much appreciated, even after the vague question you took me through the right direction. People like us look out for people like you ;) thanks a lot again :)